# hive query join on columns which are alias of max yields no result

Tags: hive, hiveql

I got two hive tables, t1 and t2, which have exactly the same content, just like shown below, two columns,'a' and 'b', and 9 rows.

```
1   a
2   b
3   c
4   d
5   e
6   f
7   g
8   h
9   i
```

problem is that the following hive_QL gets nothing,

```
select
    t2_t.a,
    t2_t.m
from
    (select
        a,
        max(b) as m
    from
        t1
    group by
        a
    ) t1_t
join
    (select
        a,
        max(b) as m
    from
        t2
    group by
        a
    ) t2_t
on
    t1_t.m=t2_t.m
```

but if I change

```
t2_t.a,
t2_t.m
```

to '*', the hive_QL works just as normal, the output would be,

```
1   a   1   a
2   b   2   b
3   c   3   c
4   d   4   d
5   e   5   e
6   f   6   f
7   g   7   g
8   h   8   h
9   i   9   i
```

my hive client version is 1.2.1, 
so please help me to understand this.

Comment: What does the column m contain?

Comment: @KaushikNayak column m is the alias of max(b) of subquery t1_t.

Comment: there is nothing wrong in this query. I tried it in my cloudera VM and your query returns the results. Have you tried it in another instance of hive?

Comment: @Ramesh Thank you for the test. I've found cause and solution of the problem, and posted them below.

Answer (score 0):

The problem happens when `IdentityProjectRemover` Optimization applied to the Operator Tree of the Hive query, SEL operator that above the FIL operator is removed incorrectly.

The SEL operator was pruning columns out of the input tuples. As a result the query returns incorrect result.

To solve this problem, `set hive.optimize.remove.identity.project=false` to turn off the optimizer.

For more details, Please refer to this Hive issue [HIVE-10996](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-10996)